# StackOverFlowError: Stack size 1036KB in AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask, resteasy

Hi I get an `StackOverflowError` while POST some small data to my server to check , if it is equal with the stored data.  I search for a while but no solution to solve my problem.

**This is my AsyncTask code:**

```
try {
        new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean>() {
            @Override
            protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... voids) {
                return serverRemoteAccessor.checkLoginData(new User("bob@bla.de", "123456"));
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Boolean aBoolean) {
                if (aBoolean){
                    Intent next = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(next);
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, 
                   "Ihre Login-Daten sind nicht korrekt, 
                    bitte überprüfen Sie Ihre Eingaben!", 
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        }.execute();

} catch (Exception e){
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error: " + e);
}
```

**ServerRemoteAccessor code:**

```
@Override
public boolean checkLoginData(User userData) {
    Log.i(LOG_TAG, "checkLogin");
    boolean isCorrect = client.checkLoginData(userData);

    Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Login is: " + isCorrect);
    return isCorrect;
}
```

**My server code :**

```
@Override
public boolean checkLoginData(User userData) {
    logger.info("checkLogin");
    User checkLogin = new User("kin@fh-bln.de","123456");
        if (checkLogin.equals(userData)){
            return true;
        }else {
            return false;
        }
}
```

**And my error message :**

> e.app.malchemie.wunderlist E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1                                                                           Process: de.app.malchemie.wunderlist, PID: 16191                                                                       java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()                                                                        at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:304)                               at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)                                                                        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)              at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
>   at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)                                                                               at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
>   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)                                                                             at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)                                                                         Caused by: java.lang.StackOverflowError: stack size 1036KB                                                                           at libcore.reflect.ListOfTypes.resolveTypes(ListOfTypes.java:70)                                                                   at libcore.reflect.ListOfTypes.getResolvedTypes(ListOfTypes.java:55)                                                                             at libcore.reflect.ParameterizedTypeImpl.getResolvedType(ParameterizedTypeImpl.java:75)                                                                        at libcore.reflect.Types.getType(Types.java:56)                                                      at java.lang.Class.getGenericSuperclass(Class.java:1195)                         at org.jboss.resteasy.util.GenericType.(GenericType.java:34)                 at org.jboss.resteasy.client.core.BaseClientResponse$1.(BaseClientResponse.java:89)                                                      at org.jboss.resteasy.client.core.BaseClientResponse.copyFromError(BaseClientResponse.java:89)                                                       at org.jboss.resteasy.client.ClientResponseFailure.(ClientResponseFailure.java:32)                                                                at org.jboss.resteasy.client.core.BaseClientResponse.createResponseFailure(BaseClientResponse.java:488)                                                       at org.jboss.resteasy.client.core.BaseClientResponse.createResponseFailure(BaseClientResponse.java:479)                                                                    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.core.BaseClientResponse.readFrom(BaseClientResponse.java:384)                                                                 at org.jboss.resteasy.client.core.BaseClientResponse.getEntity(BaseClientResponse.java:346)                                                                     at org.jboss.resteasy.client.core.BaseClientResponse.getEntity(BaseClientResponse.java:319)                                                                at org.jboss.resteasy.client.core.BaseClientResponse.getEntity(BaseClientResponse.java:442)                                                                       at org.jboss.resteasy.client.core.BaseClientResponse.copyFromError(BaseClientResponse.java:94)                                                                  at org.jboss.resteasy.client.ClientResponseFailure.(ClientResponseFailure.java:32)                                                                   at org.jboss.resteasy.client.core.BaseClientResponse.createResponseFailure(BaseClientResponse.java:488)                                                         at org.jboss.resteasy.client.core.BaseClientResponse.createResponseFailure(BaseClientResponse.java:479)                                                        at org.jboss.resteasy.client.core.BaseClientResponse.readFrom(BaseClientResponse.java:384)                                                                  at org.jboss.resteasy.client.core.BaseClientResponse.getEntity(BaseClientResponse.java:346)                                                                     at org.jboss.resteasy.client.core.BaseClientResponse.getEntity(BaseClientResponse.java:319)                                                                      at org.jboss.resteasy.client.core.BaseClientResponse.getEntity(BaseClientResponse.java:442)                                                                    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.core.BaseClientResponse.copyFromError(BaseClientResponse.java:94)                                                                  at org.jboss.resteasy.client.ClientResponseFailure.(ClientResponseFailure.java:32)                                                       at org.jboss.resteasy.client.core.BaseClientResponse.createResponseFailure(BaseClientResponse.java:488)                                                         at org.jboss.resteasy.client.core.BaseClientResponse.createResponseFailure(BaseClientResponse.java:479)                                                           at org.jboss.resteasy.client.core.BaseClientResponse.readFrom(BaseClientResponse.java:384)                                                                 at org.jboss.resteasy.client.core.BaseClientResponse.getEntity(BaseClientResponse.java:346)                                                                     at org.jboss.resteasy.client.core.BaseClientResponse.getEntity(BaseClientResponse.java:319)                                                                      at org.jboss.resteasy.client.core.BaseClientResponse.getEntity(BaseClientResponse.java:442)                                                                       at org.jboss.resteasy.client.core.BaseClientResponse.copyFromError(BaseClientResponse.java:94)                                                                     at org.jboss.resteasy.client.ClientResponseFailure.(ClientResponseFailure.java:32)                                                                  at org.jboss.resteasy.client.core.BaseClientResponse.createResponseFailure(BaseClientResponse.java:488)                                                                  at org.jboss.resteasy.client.core.BaseClientResponse.createResponseFailure(BaseClientResponse.java:479)                                                              at org.jboss.resteasy.client.core.BaseClientResponse.readFrom(BaseClientResponse.java:384)                                                                at org.jboss.resteasy.client.

EDIT:

I solve my problem, apparently my Object User was to big, so yet I POST single Strings and yea everything its okay.

Comment: Method call loop here `boolean isCorrect = client.checkLoginData(userData);` that's what causes the exception

Comment: Why? Because If i want to read my todos I use this : `ArrayList<TodoModel> todoList = client.readAllTodos();` I get no stackoverflowerror

Comment: Your method is calling itself which in turn calls itself again, this keeps happening, that's what's up

Comment: but why I get no stackoverflow error if I use this:   
`@Override
    public ArrayList<TodoModel> readAllTodos(){
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "readAllTodos");

        ArrayList<TodoModel> todoList = client.readAllTodos();

        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "readAllTodos: " + todoList);
        return todoList;
    }`

Comment: Because that method is probably not called by anybody yet

Comment: I use this method in another AsyncTask

Comment: But is that AsyncTask executed before this one AsyncTask? Does it execute successfully?

Comment: Currently I only use the AsyncTask for the checkLoginData(user) to test this method

,client is my ServerRomteAccessor interace not my ServerRemoteAccessor class

Comment: Try testing by **commenting out** everything inside the check login method which I referred to and add `return true;` to the end to see if it works

Comment: Ok I commenting out my app code not my server code and yes it works

Comment: So I posted an answer, if you think I helped find the culprit, consider accepting it as answer. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

When using Asynctask you should create tasks that could be executed within 10 seconds beyond that the consequences would be:

1. Asynctask would be interrupted
2. Asynctask loads like a lifetime unless it is being killed

Comment: Ok but I only send a small object to my server , so I think the Asynctask must executed realy fast or not ?

Comment: your internet connection is also a factor in sending a file